# how to use jdbc in Spring Bean XML "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource" is having error

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, jdbc

My error is in class it do not know `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.100:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="gjhgsdaugfjh" />
        <property name="password" value="asdfkasgdu" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: please clarify your question, what you really want to ask.

Comment: don't know what u r asking? Could u plz clarify ur question with more details?